# How to find the location where a GNU application is stored?

Tags: autostart, startup-applications, location

I am looking for running a program automatically when Ubuntu starts up. I have installed Tint2 which is a windows style taskbar. I am following the process [here](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-autostart-applications-on-ubuntu-20-04-focal-fossa-linux) for autostarting an application (Tint2) at startup.

But I cant find its binaries at \bin or \opt. Where is this application stored?

I have really spent time on this to try to locate it, despite having lots of work, so I shall really appreciate any help on this.

Comment: Program files are generally stored in /usr/bin

Comment: `$ dpkg -L tint2` will show files and locations. ....

Comment: @KnudLarsen thanks this command worked! typing tint2 in ubuntu search bar is useless as I had no results but running your command worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use the whereis command. It is included in all Ubuntu distributions.

```
whereis tint2
```

Comment: the simplest and elegant

Answer (score 1):

The package is tint2, so use apt-file (install if necessary) to list its contents:

```
apt-file list tint2
```

We see /usr/bin/tint2, so that is in your PATH and should run with just its name.
The locate command is another way to find installed things.
These days, for 20.04 and later, /bin and /usr/bin are really the same directory, so you should have found it at /bin (not backslash) too.

Comment: Also see https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=focal&arch=any&mode=exactfilename&searchon=contents&keywords=bin%2Ftint2 and https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/amd64/tint2/filelist .

Comment: makes sense. somehow Ubuntu's file search in GUI is quite useless, I didnt get any hit when I typed tint2 there. I searched it from root directory and got no  result. So command line worked.